# Angular 5 http post not working with PHP

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

I have a user form. I need user details sent to back-end. So I tried as shown below:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user-add.php", this.myform.value).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(res)
            }
        )
```

My back-end is PHP and set CORS as shown below:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization')
```

If I run this code, I am getting the below error:

```
ERROR Object { headers: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost/angular5/user-add.…", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for htt…", error: Object }  core.js:1665:5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user-add.php", this.myform.value, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(res)
            }
        )
```

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks for the response. Why we need to give responseType here?

Comment: For more information, you can read this docs https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Answer (score 0):

Not very easy to understand  but could you please write a exception handler so that you can see what exactly is wrong.

```
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
  .pipe(
    tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
    catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
  );
```

}

[Angular Heros App](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ovbplxbajpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero.service.ts)